# How can I scroll a particular node a given number of pixels using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I know that I can scroll the whole screen with `window.scrollTo()`, but this time I just want to scroll a specific node whose container is set as `overflow: scroll`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

> - Set `position:relative;` to the `container` with `overflow: scroll;`
> - Use **`block: 'start'`**, `'center'`, `'end'`, or `'nearest'` in `scrollIntoView(`) function due to smooth scroll to the chosen
>   position.

```js
var elemOutside = document.querySelector("#item");
var button1 = document.querySelector("#button");
var button2 = document.querySelector("#button-2");

button1.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  elemOutside.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end'});
},false);


var elemInside = document.getElementById("inner-element");
var topPos = elemInside.offsetTop;

button2.addEventListener("click",function(e){
   elemInside.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end'});
},false);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

#item {
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

#item p {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Go to the parent</button>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <button id="button-2">Go to the child</button>
  <li id="item">
    overflow: scroll;
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p id="inner-element">Hello!</p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
  </li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```